# PowerBI Direct Query gets data from my workspace model instead of source workspace

Tags: powerbi, directquery

I have report with data connected by direct query to dataset in workspace. When i make changes to original database the changes are not shown in my report. When i create new report the changes are there. It looks like my report created copy of the dataset and placed it in my workspace and takes data from there instead of source workspace. When i try to change it in settings it does nothing, still no changes. When i click "more information" about the dataset it opens it in my workspace instead of source even that when i was connecting it it was correct. Any idea how to handle this?

Changing source, refreshing data

Comment: When you change data from the source, did you refresh the data in power bi service? if not it will not work